# Building one project restarts entire web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Background:

- VS 2010
- C# 3.5
- Windows 7 SP1

ASP.NET web app is powered by IIS 7 in dev environment.

When I build a single project, not the "web" project, it looks like the web app is restarted. Changes made to the DLL are not taken into account since the new DLL is not deployed to bin of web project. So, why is the wep app restarted (page takes a lot of time to load)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  your `Project` is dependent on some other project, it will restart again. 
So to solve this, Please remove the project dependency from solution and try to build again.

But now you have to place the dlls manually to the other project.

Comment: It was because DLL were deployed into bin of Web project. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that will always cause recycling the Application pool (which cause the slow loading of the first pages due to compile time - which you can solve, actually). one of this things is changing the bin directory (including subfolders). maybe, somehow, when you build you change any file inside?

the other common reason for recycling the application is changing the configuration file (web.config), machine.config and global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

It May also be that you have something in your Web.Config that is invoking a change.  Perhaps try excluding your Web.Config from the publish selection so that the site stays concurrent.

Again also other things may be dependencies across other sites.  But in my personal experience its usually a web config file that causes the Application Pool to restart on demand.